# How to consume data from kafka topic in specific offset to specific offset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to consume specific offset to specific end offset!! consumer.seek() reads the data from specific offset but I need retrieve the data fromoffset to tooffset !! Any help will be appreciate , thanks in advance.

```
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    if(flag) {
        consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("topic-1", 0), 90);
        flag = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

To read messages from a start offset to an end offset, you first need to use `seek()` to move the consumer at the desired starting location and then `poll()` until you hit the desired end offset.

For example, to consume from offset 100 to 200:

```java
String topic = "test";
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);

try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(configs)) {
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic), new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {}

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            // Move to the desired start offset 
            consumer.seek(tp, 100L);
        }
    });
    boolean run = true;
    long lastOffset = 200L;
    while (run) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> crs = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100L));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : crs) {
            System.out.println(record);
            if (record.offset() == lastOffset) {
                // Reached the end offsey, stop consuming
                run = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any methods for spring Kafka ! I tried my luck but am not able to do the same thing in spring kafka