# How to get kafka offset data, specified on timestamp

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've **tried to get the offset** from Kafka topic based on timestamp when I tried to run it was throwing null pointer error,

```java
Map<TopicPartition, Long> timestampsToSearch = new HashMap<>();
              for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                timestampsToSearch.put(partition,  startTimestamp);
              }
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> outOffsets = consumer.offsetsForTimes(timestampsToSearch);
              for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                Long seekOffset = outOffsets.get(partition).offset();
consumer.seek(partition, seekOffset);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the offsets that correspond to a timestamp, you need to use the [`offsetsForTimes()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-) method.

For example, this will print the offsets for partition 0 of `mytopic` that correspond to 1 second ago:

```java
try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(configs);) {
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> timestamps = new HashMap<>();
    timestamps.put(new TopicPartition("mytopic", 0), System.currentTimeMillis()-1*1000);
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsets = consumer.offsetsForTimes(timestamps);
    System.err.println(offsets);
}
```

That will display something like:

```
{offset-test-0=(timestamp=1561469319192, leaderEpoch=0, offset=100131)}
```

Comment: My question is if we have multiple partition are there , for that I did like foreach iteration for topic partition

Comment: Just put several entries in the `timestamps` map, I just added one for the example

Comment: Am also using offsetFortimes() method, I was implemented as   mapobj  in my vode

Comment: If we don't know the partition in real-time, that case we need to iterate right??

Comment: Here again you can use the logic I provided in your other question, to retrieve the offset and seek in `onPartitionsAssigned()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413483/how-to-consume-data-from-kafka-topic-in-specific-offset-to-specific-offset/56413760#56413760
Also if these answers help or solve your issues, you can upvote and accept.

Comment: If we can't retrieve the offset on specified timestamp how to loop and get the next nearest offset?????

Comment: why would you multiply `currentTimeMillis` by `1000` ? it's already milliseconds...

Comment: It's to remove 1 second as asked in the question. 1 second by 1000 gives the number of milliseconds, which is substracted from `currentTimeMillis`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Admin.listOffsets`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#listOffsets(java.util.Map)) with [`OffsetSpec.forTimestamp`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/OffsetSpec.html#forTimestamp(long)):

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetSpec> topicOffsetSpecs = new HashMap<>();
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("topic1", 0);
OffsetSpec offsetSpec = OffsetSpec.forTimestamp(timestamp);
topicOffsetSpecs.put(topicPartition, offsetSpec);
admin.listOffsets(topicOffsetSpecs).all().get(); // Info for given timestamp
```