# retrive the offset in kafka topic based on timestamp

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i have tried to retrieved offset based on timetsamp, But when i run my code it was throwing null pointer error in here "Long seekOffset = outOffsets.get(partition).offset();" becoz that particular time there is no offset My question is how to get nearest offset on that particular timetsamp

Below code i tried,

```java
Long startTimestamp=Instant.now().minus (10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES ).toEpochMilli();

Map<TopicPartition, Long> timestampsToSearch = new HashMap<>();
              for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                timestampsToSearch.put(partition,  startTimestamp);
              }
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> outOffsets = consumer.offsetsForTimes(timestampsToSearch);
              for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
                Long seekOffset = outOffsets.get(partition).offset();
consumer.seek(partition, seekOffset);
```

Any help will be appreciate !! Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get kafka offset data, specified on timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56754704/how-to-get-kafka-offset-data-specified-on-timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

The method `offsetsForTimes`  returns the offset of the first message with timestamp greater than or equal to the target timestamp. If it is null then there is no such message. In that case just position the consumer to the end.

```
for (TopicPartition partition : partitions) {
          OffsetAndTimestamp seekOffset = outOffsets.get(partition);
          if(seekOffset!=null){
             consumer.seek(partition, seekOffset.offset()); 
          }else{
             consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singleton(partition));
          }
}
```