# How to Retrieve Kafka message fast based on key?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i have scenario where I need to test Kafka message when transaction is completed. How to retrieve the message fast using Java?  I know the key initial first 10 digit details which is unique.

Currently I am reading all partition and offset for the relevant topic which is not efficient(worst case scenario takes 2 min to get key)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible with Kafka, each Kafka partition is an append-only log that uses an offset to specify its position. The key isn't used when reading the partition.

The only way to "seek" a specific message in a partition is through its offset, so instead of reading the whole partition if you know that the message is roughly from one hour ago(or another timeframe) you can consume just that piece of information.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755255/9192615) on how to initialize a consumer on a specific offset based on timestamp in Java